# Master slave parallel processing

Tags: google-app-engine

For a genetic program, every generation is a master and every chromosome is a slave. After mutation, a chromosome has to give back the result to generation. All chromosomes of a generation can be processed  in parallel. How do I implement this in App Engine?

If I go for a taskqueue with each chromosome being a task, I face the following problems.
1. How can a chromosome give back the result to the calling generation. To store result in datastore is cumbersome (The data structure of chromosome has a KDTree)
2. How can I  notify the generation that a chromosome has completed a task so that the generation can aggregate the results from all the chromosomes and trigger the next generation ? (Polling is cumbersome.)

Taskqueue or otherwise, how do I accomplish ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could (do all that easily, that is). Taskqueues can't really communicate to each other, except through Datastore/memcache (which you seem not to want to use because your structure is a bit too big for it).

The ways you suggest seem to me to be the only way you can really do it. Maybe using Modules or endpoints could be different, but even then, you'd have some pretty cumbersome way to transfer info from one to the other.

The App Engine might not be the solution for such a use case.... maybe running something on the Compute engine, where you have more control of your threads?